# Find out what stage of the life cycle a control is up to in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net

From the outside of a control, is it possible to find out what stage of the Page LifeCycle (Init, Load, PreRender etc), a particular control or page is up to?

For example, in pseudo code:

```
if myControl.CurrentLifeCycle == Lifecycle.Init
{ do something }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no builtin function to check in what Page-Lifecycle phase a Page is.
It is also difficult to add this functionality without handling all events in the Page itself, because some events are protected. Therefore you could also inherit the LifeCycleListener-class from Control, add it in the constructor to the page listening and override all events.

If you only need the public "phases" `PreInit,Init,Load,DataBinding,PreRender,Unload,Disposed` have a look at following approach(VB.Net, but i think you'll get the idea):

```
Public Enum LifeCyclePhase
    AfterPreInit
    AfterInit
    AfterLoad
    AfterDataBinding
    AfterPreRender
    AfterUnload
    AfterDisposed
End Enum

Public Interface ITrackingLifeCycle
    ReadOnly Property GetLifeCycleListener() As LifeCycleListener
End Interface

Public Class LifeCycleListener

    Public Sub New(ByVal ctrl As Control)
        Me._PageListening = ctrl.Page
        AddListener()
    End Sub

    Private _CurrentPhase As LifeCyclePhase
    Private _PageListening As Page

    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentPhase() As LifeCyclePhase
        Get
            Return _CurrentPhase
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property PageListening() As Page
        Get
            Return _PageListening
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub AddListener()
        AddHandler _PageListening.PreInit, AddressOf PreInit
        AddHandler _PageListening.Init, AddressOf Init
        AddHandler _PageListening.Load, AddressOf Load
        AddHandler _PageListening.DataBinding, AddressOf DataBinding
        AddHandler _PageListening.PreRender, AddressOf PreRender
        AddHandler _PageListening.Unload, AddressOf Unload
        AddHandler _PageListening.Disposed, AddressOf Disposed
    End Sub

    Private Sub PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me._CurrentPhase = LifeCyclePhase.AfterPreInit
    End Sub

    Private Sub Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me._CurrentPhase = LifeCyclePhase.AfterInit
    End Sub

    Private Sub Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me._CurrentPhase = LifeCyclePhase.AfterLoad
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataBinding(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me._CurrentPhase = LifeCyclePhase.AfterDataBinding
    End Sub

    Private Sub PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me._CurrentPhase = LifeCyclePhase.AfterPreRender
    End Sub

    Private Sub Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me._CurrentPhase = LifeCyclePhase.AfterUnload
    End Sub

    Private Sub Disposed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me._CurrentPhase = LifeCyclePhase.AfterDisposed
    End Sub
End Class
```

The handler in this class are called after the handler in the page itself, so if you f.e. check the CurrentPhase in Page.Init you'll get PreInit. Therefor i have called this phase AfterPreInit.

```
Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Implements ITrackingLifeCycle

    Private lcl As New LifeCycleListener(Me)

    Public ReadOnly Property GetLifeCycleListener() As LifeCycleListener Implements ITrackingLifeCycle.GetLifeCycleListener
        Get
            Return lcl
        End Get
    End Property
```

You can now check the lifecycle-phase everywhere, even without a reference to a control via HttpContext.Current:

```
Public Class FooClass
    Public Shared Sub Foo()
        If Not (HttpContext.Current Is Nothing OrElse HttpContext.Current.Handler Is Nothing) Then
            If TypeOf HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler Is ITrackingLifeCycle Then
                Dim page As ITrackingLifeCycle = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler, ITrackingLifeCycle)
                Dim phase As LifeCyclePhase = page.GetLifeCycleListener.CurrentPhase
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is neither tested sufficiently nor used by myself and certainly improvable, but maybe it helps you in your current situation.

Comment: A cool bit of code - it looks like overkill for my particular scenario, but I'm still impressed.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you try to achieve is conceptually wrong because you are thinking at the page events as page state. The page can’t be at “OnInit/OnLoad/…” state just because it’s an event.

What do you need it for? maybe we could suggest you a better approach to achieve your goal.

Comment: I am creating a wrapper around a third party module. The module requires that certain methods are called during OnLoad - not before and not after. I am trying to 'improve' the module by either throwing an informative exception, or by diverting calls during OnInit to the OnLoad stage - I can do either these of these if I know what stage the lifecycle is up to.

Comment: I disagree that the page lifecycle should not be thought of as a state. That may be the way that is implemented by Microsoft, but the documented concept of 'page lifecycle' is certainly a state-based concept, and in fact it is quite easy to inherit from Page and create a variable that keeps track of the current state yourself.

Comment: Why don't you use  a Delagate then? You can create a delegate that point to the wrapper method and invoke it within the OnLoad/OnInit/... method

Comment: I disagree cbp. The event is just a notification that something is happening : the page is loading, the page in rendering, etc  
The page is loading, for instance, doesn’t mean the page is at “Load State” but it’s just notify you that asp.net is calling the “OnLoad” method.
It looks more similar to the “event driven pattern” then the “State pattern”.
just to make more clear this concept : how can you set the page state at “OnLoad state” ? you can’t . you can just do something when asp.net  notify you the “OnLoad” is happening
I hope it makes sense

Comment: I can see what you are saying - maybe a better way to phrase it than as 'state', is 'Has Event X Been Fired'.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso: Why can't you understand the page's lifelcylcle events as a state transition?  It's not required that you must be able to set a state per definition, is it? Imho an event is always a  change in state.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I see what you are saying but an event is not always a change of state
"Event. An occurrence that MAY trigger a state transition. Event types include an explicit signal from outside the system, an invocation from inside the system, the passage of a designated period of time, or a designated condition becoming true."

Answer (score 3):

The „outside of your control” is the „inside” of another control or page or something being in a linked state of the lifecycle. You know its state already without testing.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, but that's not always the case - certainly not in my case. But perhaps something to think about.

Answer (score 3):

I found out there is actually an internal property of the Page class that does just what I am looking for: it is an enum called ControlState:

```
internal enum ControlState
{
Constructed,
FrameworkInitialized,
ChildrenInitialized,
Initialized,
ViewStateLoaded,
Loaded,
PreRendered
}
```

I believe it is possible to access internal members in C#4, see [here](http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2010/05/accessprivatewrapper-c-40-dynamic.html)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the page lifecycle, you can't do it. Basically, Page class is the guy   that has to raise events in a specific order. There is nothing in built that will tell the stage of processing. But in order to something, you can create a property and set up this property in different stages of processing.