# Can I know if the Preinit event of my aspx page has been fired yet?

Tags: asp.net, events, lifecycle

Can I know if the Preinit event of my aspx page has been fired yet?

I need some code to run after Instantiation but before "anything else" that might execute after PreInit.

So this leave me to either call my code from within a PreInit event handler before it gets fired or immediately if PreInit has already been fired.

Comment: Does my `LifeCycleListener` help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094745/find-out-what-stage-of-the-life-cycle-a-control-is-up-to-in-asp-net-webforms

Comment: Thank you but I'd like to know of a native way to do it if it exists.